# Find best match for list of strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to solve the following problem. In my database are different strings linked to a date. Every date will have about three to twenty strings linked to it when the system is running.

Now I would like to send a query to the database with a list of strings. The database should return me the date which has the most strings in common with the query.

I made a sample database that you can create with the SQL script appended to this post. In this sample my query would contain the strings `“abc”, “yz”, “def”, “jkl”`. The database should then order the date according to the amount of matched stings. This means `(100, '2005-05-05 05:05:05')` should be the first and `(103, '2008-08-08 08:08:08')` should be the last. There is no need to sort the ones with an equal amount of matching strings further with respect to another criteria.

I’m running MySQL 5.5.11. How can I achieve that goal?

```
    CREATE  TABLE sampledate(
      id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL );

CREATE  TABLE  properties(
  idprop INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  property VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  iddate INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (iddate) REFERENCES sampledate(id)
);

INSERT INTO sampledate (id, time) VALUES ( 100, '2005-05-05 05:05:05');
INSERT INTO sampledate (id, time) VALUES ( 101, '2006-06-06 06:06:06');
INSERT INTO sampledate (id, time) VALUES ( 102, '2007-07-07 07:07:07');
INSERT INTO sampledate (id, time) VALUES ( 103, '2008-08-08 08:08:08');

INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (201, "abc", 100);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (202, "def", 100);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (203, "ghi", 100);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (204, "jkl", 100);

INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (301, "def", 101);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (302, "mno", 101);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (303, "pqr", 101);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (304, "stu", 101);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (305, "vwx", 101);

INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (401, "vwx", 102);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (402, "pqr", 102);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (403, "ghi", 102);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (404, "mno", 102);

INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (501, "vwx", 103);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (502, "mno", 103);
INSERT INTO properties (idprop, property, iddate) VALUES (503, "yz", 103);
```

Comment: I don't think 102 should be in the result set at all. You probably meant 103.

Comment: I'm confused by the phase, "according to the amount of matched strings". Does that suggest that you want some sort of fuzzy matching and/or inclusion of dates when there is no match whatsoever?

Comment: Can the `properties.property` column have duplicates for any single `iddate`? If so, should the distinct count be applied?

Comment: @Andriy M: +1 for noticing that. Yes, since the table allows it, you can have more than one row for the same date and property. I edited my answer to show how to do that, but I'd consider this a design mistake, myself. I'd guess that a UNIQUE constraint on (iddate, property) is called for. (And that idprop isn't necessary at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the number of matches.

```
select iddate, count(iddate) as num_dates
from properties
where property in ('abc', 'yz', 'def', 'jkl')
group by iddate
order by num_dates desc
```

To get the date data, just join to that query.

```
select t1.*, t2.num_dates
from sampledate t1
inner join 
    (select iddate, count(iddate) as num_dates
     from properties
     where property in ('abc', 'yz', 'def', 'jkl')
     group by iddate) t2
on t1.id = t2.iddate
order by num_dates desc
```

If the count actually needs to be based on the number of properties, because the table allows one date to have many rows where the property = 'abc', then you'd just count that column instead of 'iddate'.

```
select t1.*, t2.num_props
from sampledate t1
inner join 
    (select iddate, count(distinct property) as num_props
     from properties
     where property in ('abc', 'yz', 'def', 'jkl')
     group by iddate) t2
on t1.id = t2.iddate
order by num_props desc ;
```